# Correct mysql trigger syntax to prevent infinite loop

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating the following test trigger to update the value of a field whenever an `UPDATE` operation occurs:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `test_index` 
AFTER UPDATE ON `main_itemmaster` 
FOR EACH ROW  
    UPDATE `main_itemmaster` SET `guid` = "hello" WHERE `id` = NEW.id;
```

However, whenever I do an update to this table I get the following error:

```
Can't update table 'main_itemmaster' in stored function/trigger 
because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

Why is this occurring and how would I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you want to do?

Clearly you cannot update same table on updating... It become circular.

Do you want to update on insert? That should be possible:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `test_index` 
AFTER INSERT ON `main_itemmaster` 
FOR EACH ROW  
UPDATE `main_itemmaster` SET `guid` = "hello" WHERE `id` = NEW.id;
```

I saw your comment. I propose this:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER test_index BEFORE UPDATE ON main_itemmaster
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    IF NEW.name <> OLD.name OR NEW.location<>OLD.location THEN
           SET NEW.guid = concat(NEW.name, NEW.location);
       END IF;
   END;//
delimiter ;
```

I tested it and it works! Also if you update only one field.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Here is what I'm trying to accomplish. Let's say I have three fields, `name+location+guid`, and whenever I update the location or name of a row, I also want the guid to update to `concat(name, location)`. How would I do that?

Comment: See updated answer (I forgot to put concat(NEW.name, NEW.location)). I tested it and it works.